# how to send data from esp32 to raspberry pi using wi-fi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, esp32

i hope you're doing great !

I'm currently working on a project from  long time ago and honestly that was  depressing for me , well i'm going to share with you the idea and the progress I made through the past 5 weeks and  hope if you someone of you can lead or help me ,

so the idea is I'm currently connecting esp32 Arduino board with temperature sensors (dht22) ,
I'm able to connect this sensor to esp32 and read all the values on the serial monitor .

now my next step that I didn't know how to do is :

I want to send the serial monitor data continuously every 2 min to the raspberry pi via the wi-fi , i want to program those data to be seen on thingsboard .

thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

You can use MQTT method to send your esp32 data to the desired computer or multiple computers. Install the MQTT broker software in the raspberry. Connect the esp32 to that MQTT broker and publish your data to a specific topic. In the application you can connect to the same broker and subscribe to that topic and receive the data stream.

Comment: That's how you do it. Alternatively, if you want to send data to thingsboard then they also support MQTT - so you could send there directly from the ESP without bothering with the RPi